# How to confugure multiple info log files as module specific in dropwizard 0.6.2

Tags: dropwizard

If i add appender in yaml file it is showing error like below

Error :

> Unrecognized field "appenders" (class
>   com.yammer.dropwizard.config.LoggingConfiguration$FileConfiguration)
>
> com.yammer.dropwizard.config.LoggingConfiguration["file"]-
>
> > com.yammer.dropwizard.config.FileConfiguration["appenders"])

My yaml file looks like this:

```
logging:

  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO,
  # DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO

  # ...
  # Settings for logging to stdout.
  console:

    # If true, write log statements to stdout.
    enabled: true

    # Do not display log statements below this threshold to stdout.
    threshold: ALL

    # The time zone in which dates should be displayed.
    timeZone: UTC

    # A custom Logback format string.
    logFormat: null

  # Settings for logging to a file.
  file:

    # If true, write log statements to a file.
    enabled: true

    # Do not write log statements below this threshold to the file.
    threshold: ALL

    # The file to which current statements will be logged.
    currentLogFilename: ./logs/mylog.log

    # When the log file rotates, the archived log will be renamed to this and gzipped. The
    # %d is replaced with the previous day (yyyy-MM-dd). Custom rolling windows can be created
    # by passing a SimpleDateFormat-compatible format as an argument: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}".
    archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/example-%d.log.gz

    # The number of archived files to keep.
    archivedFileCount: 5

    # The timezone used to format dates. HINT: USE THE DEFAULT, UTC.
    timeZone: UTC


  appenders:
  - type: file.
    currentLogFilename: ./logs/example1.log
    archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/example1-%d.log.gz
    archivedFileCount: 5
```

Any help?

Comment: Please include in the question the yaml file, in particular the section for logging and appenders. Thanks.

Comment: Hi André Barbosa Please find above yaml file

Answer (score 0):

I have been comparing the manuals for both versions 0.6.2 and 0.7.0 of DropWizard and seems like the appenders feature was introduced only in 0.7.0:

http://www.dropwizard.io/0.6.2/manual/core.html#logging

http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.0/docs/manual/core.html#logging

So the solution to this issue should be to upgrade to a 0.7.0+ version of DW.